# How to embed a file excerpt in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, nbconvert

I would like to disclose a part of my code inside a Markdown cell in Jupyter. The code is located in an external file. Concretely, I am looking for something like:

`[file.py:240:255]`

which would display the lines 240 to 255 of `file.py`.

I wonder how this can be achieved. I guess we can write a script inside nbconvert, but this kind of features might already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the built-in jupyter command [`%load`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-load).

```
%load -r 240-255 path/to/file.py
```

The cell must be in code mode to execute this command. The only problem is that the code is not highlighted when the cell type is changed to markdown.